# Объединение таблиц с заполнением не пересекающихся по ключам строк значением 'N/A'

Tags: sql, sqlite3

Есть две таблички

```
  -first_table-        -second_table-
|--var--|-value-|    |--var--|-value-|
| int   |   1   |    | float |  2.0  |
| float |  1.0  |    | char  |   b   |
| char  |   a   |    | bool  | false |
|-------|-------|    |-------|-------|
```

Я хочу сделать запрос UNION ALL по всем возможным переменным для обоих таблиц так, что бы если какой-либо переменной нет в таблице, её значение было "N/A".

код:

```
CREATE TABLE first_table ( var text, value text );
CREATE TABLE second_table ( var text, value text );

INSERT INTO first_table VALUES( 'int', '1' );
INSERT INTO first_table VALUES( 'float', '1.0' );
INSERT INTO first_table VALUES( 'char', 'a' );

INSERT INTO second_table VALUES( 'float', '2.0' );
INSERT INTO second_table VALUES( 'char', 'b' );
INSERT INTO second_table VALUES( 'bool', 'false' );
```

далее

```
echo "SELECT var,value FROM 'first_table' WHERE var='int' UNION ALL SELECT var,value FROM 'first_table' WHERE var='float' UNION ALL SELECT var,value FROM 'first_table' WHERE var='char' UNION ALL SELECT var,value FROM 'first_table' WHERE var='bool' UNION ALL SELECT var,value FROM 'second_table' WHERE var='int' UNION ALL SELECT var,value FROM 'second_table' WHERE var='float' UNION ALL SELECT var,value FROM 'second_table' WHERE var='char' UNION ALL SELECT var,value FROM 'second_table' WHERE var='bool' ;" | sqlite3 test.db 
int|1
float|1.0
char|a
float|2.0
char|b
bool|false
```

а надо что бы было

```
int|1
float|1.0
char|a
bool|N/A
int|N/A
float|2.0
char|b
bool|false
```

Comment: Получите полный список всех `var` в подзапросе, `left  join` таблицы к нему, `union all` двух таких подзапросов.

Comment: список всех `var`: `SELECT var FROM 'first_table' UNION SELECT var FROM 'second_table' ;` теперь его `left join`? а где 'N/A' будет?

Comment: Не его. К нему left join одну из таблиц. Чтобы заменить Null на N/A, пользуем COALESCE(). То же делаем ещё с одним подзапросом и второй таблицей. И UNION ALL этих двух запросов.

Comment: не понимаю. можно код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select V.var,
       coalesce(case when num=1 then F.value else S.value end, 'N/A') value
  from
   (select var from first_table
     union
    select var from second_table
   ) V
 cross join (select 1 as num union select 2) N
  left join first_table F  on N.num=1 and F.var=V.var
  left join second_table S on N.num=2 and S.var=V.var
 order by N.num, V.var desc
```

Второй вариант:

```
with X(var,value,num) as (
    select var, value, 1 from first_table
     union all
    select var, value, 2 from second_table
  )
 select * from X
 union all
 select var, 'N/A', 3-max(num) from X group by var having count(1)=1
 order by num, var desc
```

Comment: Какие-то сложные запросы. Надо-то всего навсего - объединить две таблицы...

Comment: @sqkgkahaew Ну объединить было бы коротко, а вот создать не существующие записи ... собственно во втором варианте это отлично видно, потому что они явно создаются отдельной строчкой. И кстати, вариант, изначально предложенный akina в два раза длиннее, так что еще легко отделались :)